# Permissions for Java application on Ubuntu

Tags: java, netbeans, permissions, rcp

I have a NetBeans RCP application that's currently working on Windows and I'm trying to make Linux compatible. The application creates folders and files and modify files as well.

It works fine on Windows without any modification but on Ubuntu it fails creating folders during start up. I know it's a permission issue.

What are my options?

Can the application itself assign the permissions it needs like by running a script using ProcessBuilder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give us the stacktrace, are you absolutely sure you are creating in the user directory is this a real user?  There is no direct way of switching user, although like you could have a sudo command in a script you and do the permission assignment but you will have to have someway of providing a password and assumes the user has permission do this.

Comment: I'll add a stack trace when I get back home to Ubuntu machine. I know is the real user because I use user.home property to reach the folder. Also other folders and files are created there when the application starts.

Comment: Sorry, by real user I meant a real person, and not a user for say some service like apache or oracle

Comment: The user is the user running the app. Here's part of the error:

Comment: The user is the user running the app. I created the folder that it was complaining about but it failed down the road anyway:org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Log file error: "/home/javier\marauroa.trace.db", cause: "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: ""java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/javier\marauroa.trace.db (Permission denied)""; ""/home/javier\marauroa.trace.db"" [90031-128]" [90034-128] Is an embedded database that can't create some files.

Comment: Instructions to get the code: https://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=325779

Comment: Please add the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: @javy: Updated my answer to include what I think of the exception.

Comment: Nothing to do with the \ instead of /?  I use linux/java pretty much all the time (ironically I'm on windows at the minute so can't check) but don't remember ever trying \ in a path, try using fileSeperator to construct the path

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on who you are when running the process on Ubuntu, and the path of the folders that you're trying to create.  Does this user have permissions to create the folders in that directory?  What sort of data are you writing out to disk?  Can you use a platform neutral mechanism thats user oriented, like Java [Preferences](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) or perhaps:

`System.getProperty("user.home"`)
-or-
`System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`?

Comment: See above comment for details.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to create required folders as part of a setup process or restrict your IO to folders you have access to (the users home and the temp folder). Notice that on Linux there are standard locations where many folders should be placed and that administrators will frown upon applications that do not follow these standards.

Can you tell what files/folders you need for what purpose?

Looks like the cause of the problem is the difference in path delimiter between Windows and Linux. On linux you should use normal slashes. The error mentions the path:

```
/home/javier\marauroa.trace.db
```

As the \ is not a path delimiter but the escape character it is trying to create a file in the folder /home where it does not have permissions.

The path should be:

```
/home/javier/marauroa.trace.db
```

You might want to consider putting your apps files in a subfolder called .yourappname so then it would become

```
/home/javier/.yourappname/marauroa.trace.db
```

This is what many unix applications do and hide it in normal file listings. To get the path seperator for the system your application is running on you can use the following static field:

```
java.io.File.seperator
```

Comment: The think is that I'm working on the user home. I'm able to create some folders but when I try starting a java application (using ProcessBuilder) that needs to create some folders I get a permission exception.

Comment: Can you give more details like error messages and the code causing them?

Comment: What I recall is that the application is trying to create a log file (Log 4 J) during start up and is failing.

Comment: Hmm, is weird because I do have an application subfolder named .Marauroa-Server-Manager. Before attempting to start the application (using ProcessBuilder) I set the path for the builder to: System.getProperty("user.home")+ System.getProperty("file.separator") + ".Marauroa-Server-Manager"+ System.getProperty("file.separator")+ "Applications" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + getName()+ System.getProperty("file.separator") Which would be something like: home/javier/.Marauroa-Server-Manager/Applications/Test/

Comment: marauroa.trace.db is being created by H2 database. For some reason it is using the wrong backslash I guess.

Comment: In Windows everything works within the aplication folder including the database files.